# gem install rails gives me Error: undefined method include?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm using ubuntu 9.10, apache 2 and mysql 5.  I install ruby 1.8.7 on the server.  I ran the command

```
gem install rails -v 1.2.3
```

But then I get the error

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I formatted the disk and installed everything all over again.  I was trying to replicate the settings of a very old ruby on rails server.  So this time I  made sure I had the correct version of all the old dependent gems.  This seemed to have solved "some" of the problems.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need:

```
gem install rails -v=1.2.3
```

or gem will think that 1.2.3 is a new gem to install, add the = sign.